# Can't use integer values in a redis key

Tags: scala, redis

I want to add data to redis:

```
object Obj1 {
  val redis = new RedisClient
  def insert(): Unit = {
    val data = List(
      (111, 222, 333),
      (444, 555, 666)
    )
    for ((x, i) <- data.zipWithIndex) {
      redis lpush (f"key1$i", x._1)
      redis lpush (f"key2$i", x._2)
    }
  }
}
```

It complains at runtime:

```
[error] (run-main) java.lang.Exception: ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
java.lang.Exception: ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

And it does it due to `$i` for some reason. Even "key123" causes the error.

Client https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis

Comment: Can you specify which client? There seems to be a couple: http://redis.io/clients#Java

Comment: @krivachy.akos, I did.

Comment: Have you tried with `s` interpolation? Don't think that you actually need `f` in this case.

Comment: @krivachy.akos, I did and failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works absolutely fine using **Scala 2.10.3** with **Scala-Redis 2.11** even with String interpolation. Tried on IntelliJ with SBT 0.13.

Try updating to the latest version of the client (if you are using an older version). If you are using SBT :

```
libraryDependencies += "net.debasishg" % "redisclient_2.10" % "2.11"
```